# Need help with integration by parts

Tags: integration

I absolutely despise integration by parts, because it never seems to work for me. Here's an example:

$$ \int 4x \sin(2x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

What I did:

$$ \int 4x \sin(2x) \, \mathrm{d}x = -2x \cos(2x) - \int - 4\cos(2x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Here I'm already stuck. I know about the ILATE/LIATE/whatever but it didn't work out for me either. What should I do at this juncture?

Comment: Why you stuck there? Latter looks like pretty easy integral to take, doesn't it?

Comment: @Kaster not helpful... when you're stuck on a problem, it is never fun to hear that "it looks easy, doesn't it?"

Comment: Damn, I thought previous comment came from OP. My bad. @anorton let OP to decide was it fun or not. Agreed?

Comment: @Kaster Agreed.  I just know that whenever I leave a comment like that, it tends to backfire. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done the hard part of the integration by parts right; you're just off by a constant multiple.  If we let $u = 4x,\; dv=\sin(2x)dx \implies du = 4\,dx,\;v=\frac{-\cos(2x)}{2}$.

When we put this together:
$$\begin{align}uv - \int v\,du &= -2x\cos(2x) + \int\left(\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}\right)4\,dx\\
&=-2x\cos(2x) + \int2\cos(2x)\,dx
\end{align}$$
So, that's basically where you're at (except for the $2$ instead of the $4$).  At this point, we can use $u$ substitution.

**Hint:**

> Let $u = 2x$.

Answer (score 2):

Now just pull the $-4$ out of the integral and integrate $\cos (2x)$ the same way you integrated $\sin (2x)$